# SPGridView Edit Causeing postback and Grid Disappears

Tags: spgridview

I have created a webpart with an SPGrid that is created after an onclick event.  The grid displays with an "Edit" Button.  When I click on the edit button it causes a postback and the grid disappears.    How can I change the

Comment: Could you paste the whole web part code here?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're calling the code in right order.

```
   protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

       // you code here

       Controls.Add(yourgridviewid);

       //Important to call this after Control.Add...

       yourgridviewid.PagerTemplate = null;
       base.CreateChildControls();
    }
```

Comment: I solved the issue.  I was adding the control on a button_click event which was causing a postback and I didn't include the grid on the postback.  Thank you for your help.